# What does awk '/a/ {print $4 "\t" $3} abc.txt mean?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am learning awk and I was confused with the following command:

```
awk '/a/ {print $4 "\t" $3}' abc.txt
```

What does `/a/` mean? I was reading the **Sed & awk, 2nd Edition** by **Dale Dougherty**. Probably, I didn't reach that part of `/a/` text processing part. Hence asked this question.

Comment: it's a regular expression, basically "find all letter `a` in the line".

Comment: Looking at that question you haven't put much effort into researching awk =D

Comment: @MarcB: really? it looks like it just prints column 4 and 3 separated by tab.

Comment: @l'L'l: but only if there's a letter `a` in the line

Comment: @l'L'l Why do there have to be three delimited characters? If the line consists of `a` and nothing else, `$3` and `$4` are just empty, but the line gets still printed (containing just a tab character).

Comment: @BenjaminW: yes, that's fairly obvious ... I was referring to actually printing the `a` character.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for every line in the abc.txt file it test if it has a "a" character. If it does prints the fourth word in that line, then a tab character and then the third word.

Comment: Thanks guys understood!

Comment: Thanks, Roberto and others for solution. May be at that time, I was not aware of this concept. Can you please upvote my question, as I am being locked out of asking more questions. I have done my best to improve this question.